# How to run a JavaScript code inside of a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I open a jquery dialog, it opens very good, the content of this dialog is a form, one input of that form is:

```
<input onkeyup="testOnKeyUp();" type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
```

Here is where come my problem, it's suppose that when someone type a Key in this input the following code is activated and should run, but it just does not work.

```
var validateUserNameSpan = $j('#userNameSpan');

function testOnKeyUp(){
validate(this, validateUserNameSpan, 'username');
}

function validate(field, span, property) {

if (field.value != field.lastValue) {
if (field.timer) clearTimeout(field.timer);

field.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    span.value = "";
    span.removeClass('error').html('checking ...');
    $j.ajax({
        url: '/signup/'+property,
        data: property + '=' + field.value,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (json) {
            updateMessage(span, json.success, json.message);
            if(property=="email"){
                emailValid = true;
            }else if(property=="username"){
                userNameValid = true;
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            ajFailureInitSignup(span);
            if(property=="email"){
                emailValid = false;
            }else if(property=="username"){
                userNameValid = false;
            }
        }
    });
}, 400);


if(userNameValid && emailValid) document.getElementById('buttonLink').onclick=null ;

field.lastValue = field.value;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I don't know but googling I've got info that make me feel that the:

```
$j.ajax({
```

that I'm running inside of this dialog (validate function) is not being executed, why I say that ? because this dialog is created in the DOM and after be created there this $j.ajax is not executed.

is this true ?

I really thank any help.

Comment: Are you actually attaching that testonKeyup function to the popup form's inputs?

Comment: yes I do, actually if I place an alert message inside the function testOnKeyUp(); the alert is shown, which mean that when the user write a Key the process is working fine until this function, the problem looks to be inside the validate() function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the main problem is that your AJAX call returns IMMEDIATELY after you issue it - this is normal (it's the first 'A' in ajax - asynchronous). That means your code continues on immediately to the `if (usernamevalid && emailvalid)` code section. Those variables do not exist at that point, as the AJAX call has not yet returned. So you're comparing undefined variables, which will also fail.

You have to move that comparison inside your ajax success/error handlers, so that the comparison will only be done when the ajax call has actually produced data that can be compared.

Comment: ok, but when I load exactly this form in another page (not like dialog box) this work pefectly and execute the $j.ajax propertly. is there a difference in this dialog way about you said?